# How to catch Stripe responses details with the default embedded payment form?

Tags: javascript, request, stripe-payments, response, stripe.js

After reading this:

[Stripe Custom Checkout With Options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47721174/6225838)

I understand that it is not possible to get the details from what is typed-in in the Stripe iframe.

What about the response's details? For example, when I click to pay with an expired test card, I can observe this in the console (*Network* tab):

```
error {
  code: 'expired_card'
  doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/expired-card'
  message: 'Your card has expired.'
  param: 'exp_month'
  type: 'card_error'
}
```

My goal is to get that message and display it in my own popup (since Stripe only does this for a few types of errors).

I tried some [Stripe error tags already (docs)](https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/STRIPES/pages/491985/Display+Errors) in the page where I load their payment form, but they seem to not get updated with any content...

Is there any other way to catch these responses details? Or do I need something else for these to show up?

**Note**: I am not performing the requests myself - I need to use the default checkout form loaded by Stripe (similar to the "Pay by Card" button in this [quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart) while using these [Stripe test cards](https://stripe.com/docs/testing)).

Answer (score 0):

Did you scroll down on the quickstart page? There's code right there on how to send the data to your server.

```
    <form action="your-server-side-code" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Stripe.com"
    data-description="Example charge"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-zip-code="true">
  </script>
</form>
```

From there you can send whatever response you need back from the server to your front end.

Comment: Do you mean the `action` attribute? I actually have an URL pointing to a method in my server, but it seems nothing is passed through...

Comment: No, sorry. The form is almost identical to the one you copy-pasted. The method in my server is outputting an encoded JSON.

Comment: Oh sorry. It seems that the error you are getting is a direct response from Stripe's server after using Checkout. I don't think you will be able to manipulate the response. But on the front end you can do something such as checking the code and `if code == 'expired_card'` then set your error message that you want

Comment: The thing is, in [their docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#errors) it is written that _messages_ "can be shown to your users", but when I press the pay button the request to my server is not made... This is why I was wondering.